# Is there a recommended way to use `if let` with a floating-point value?

Tags: rust, floating-point, pattern-matching

I'm doing some argument parsing and eventually I end up with a value which is an `Option<f64>` which is initially `None`, but can be `Some(n)` if the user passes the program `-g n`. However, if the user says `-g 0` I end up with a `Some(0.0)` which I want to translate into `None`. So I do:

```
if let Some(0.0) = config.opt_value {
    config.opt_value = None;
}
```

That seems simple enough, but the compiler gives me a warning, which I quote:

```
warning: floating-point types cannot be used in patterns
 --> src/lib.rs:2:17
  |
2 |     if let Some(0.0) = config.opt_value {
  |                 ^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(illegal_floating_point_literal_pattern)]` on by default
  = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
  = note: for more information, see issue #41620 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41620>
```

This message directs me to [the Rust tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41620), which refers to [Rust RFC 1445: Restrict constants in patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1445). There is a longish discussion, but not much in the way of how we are supposed to fix the warning. The RFC comes up with using match arm guards to do regular comparison on the float values:

```rust
match value { n if n == 0.0 => { /* whatever */ } }
```

This doesn't work in `if let` (so no `if let Some(n) if n == 0.0 { /* whatever */ }` for me).

I've managed to come up with

```rust
match config.opt_value {
    Some(n) if n == 0.0 => { config.opt_value = None },
    _ => {}
};
```

This is ugly as sin but will get the job done.

Is there a recommended way to use `if let` on floating point types in response to the above warning, or are we on our own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [`Option::map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) (or equivalent methods):

```
if config.opt_value.map_or(false, |v| v == 0.0)
```

For your broader case, I'd use [`Option::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter)

```
let value = config.opt_value.filter(|&v| v != 0.0);
```

See also:

- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic: Comparison](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)
- [Alternatives to matching floating points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45875142/155423)

Answer (score 4):

> There is a longish discussion, but not much in the way of how we are supposed to fix the warning.

I'd just use an ordinary non-pattern-matching `if`:

```rust
    if config.opt_value == Some(0.0) {
        // ...
    }
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57e1e05cd21e3a4f38e539a439a66c16))